# $Action.MyObject__c.Share is not valid for this Organization

Tags: visualforce, sharing, global-actions

On a `VisualForce Page`, I have a merge field:

```
{!URLFOR($Action.MyObject__c.Share, MyObject__c.Id)}
```

When I try to save it to server, I am getting the error:

> Action $Action.MyObject__c.Share is not valid for this Organization (in function URLFOR)

Why would I get this error? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Your error message says "$Acion".  Do you have a typo in your code that should read "$Action" ?

Comment: Just a typo, the code snippet is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think share would only exist as a valid object if sharing is enabled on My_Object__c - so I would check the sharing rules...